# Get jquery data attributes from a form's select's option's values

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the values of `data` from the `options` in the form below, so I can use them in jQuery, but I somehow don't seem to be succeeding. What I'm trying to do is simple, and you'll see in my code below. How can I do something like this?

```
$('#selectForm').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var action = $(this).data('id');
        var type = $(this).data('name');

        console.log(action+' '+type);
    });
```

//Jquery

```
<form id="selecttest">
    <label for="fruit">Please select at least two fruits</label><br>
        <select id="fruit" name="fruit" size="5">
            <option data-id="1" data-name="norman">Banana</option>
            <option data-id="2" data-name="james">Apple</option>
            <option data-id="3" data-name="lars">Peach</option>
            <option data-id="4" data-name="john">Turtle</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" id="selectForm" value="Validate Selecttests">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

here is demo - http://jsfiddle.net/tnVfV/

here is code:

```
$('#selectForm').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var action = $('#fruit option:selected').attr('data-id');
    var type = $('#fruit option:selected').attr('data-name');

    console.log(action + ' ' + type);
});
```

`data-id` and `data-name` are attributes of options. There are native attributes `id` and `name` you could use...

---

ok as per tymeJV comment here is code using `data()`:

```
$('#selectForm').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var action = $('#fruit option:selected').data('id');
    var type = $('#fruit option:selected').data('name');

    console.log(action + ' ' + type);
});
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/tnVfV/1/

Comment: Change `attr` to `.data("id")`

Comment: To pull out custom data attributes, you should use `.data`. Per jQuery API: The .data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
var action = $("#fruit option:selected").attr('data-id');
var type = $("#fruit option:selected").attr('data-name');
```

Comment: $(this) will refer to $('#selectForm') in $('#selectForm').click(function() {...});

Comment: Not really an answer as the user specifically asks about using jquery data methods for data-attributes

Answer (score 2):

`var id = $('#fruit').find(':selected').data('id');
var name = $('#fruit').find(':selected').data('name');`

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `prop` in the place on attr

[prop documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

You can access selected option's attribute `data-name` like this:

```
$('#fruit option:selected').attr('data-name');
```

So try this

```
$('#selectForm').click(function(e) {

    // better add this part of code for cross-browser functionality:
    var event = (window.event || e); 

    event.preventDefault();

    var data-name = $('#fruit option:selected').attr('data-name');

});
```

Comment: I know that jQuery is cross-browser, I don't think that extra check is necessary at all.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea yes, jQuery is. But this is common practice with events

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following in your code

```
$('#selectForm').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var select = $("#fruit")[0].selectedIndex;
    var id= $("#fruit option:eq("+select+")").data("id");
    var type=$("#fruit option:eq("+select+")").data("name");
    console.log(id +" "+ type)          
});
```